# Search Embedded List

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, document-library, modern-experience, sitepages

I have embedded a document library from another SharePoint site in my own site, which works great. However when I use the search bar on that page, it does not search for documents from the embedded list, is there a way to configure this? Or at least make the embedded list searchable?

Much appreciated!

FYI - Using SharePoint online.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior in SharePoint online.

SharePoint search box will not search content from another SharePoint site when it is added to site using [Embed web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8) and you are using "Current site" option like:

[image]

If another site is from same tenant/organization, you can use "Whole organization" option to search the content from another site, like:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I was expecting it to behave this way also. I was just wondering if there was a way to add a search function? If I recall in SharePoint on prem, if you embedded a site it would add a search bar in the list navigation bar.

Comment: Try using "Whole organization" option as shown. Let us know if it works for you.

Comment: Strangely, I don't have the option in my site, I wonder if its locked down as were a large organization and searching all the SharePoint sites I think would be an issue.

Comment: Check this documentation for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/manage-spo-search-box

Comment: Hi @LukeWilson, please [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

You could check these options:
1.Library settings ->advance settings-> search -> Allow items from this document library to appear in search results? -> Yes.

2.Site collection settings-> manage result sources, make sure the document option in active.